# How to delete files under subdirectories but not deleting subdirectories themselves in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have the following directory structure:

```
/archive/file1.csv
/archive/file2.csv
/archive/myfile/my.txt
/archive/yourfile/your.txt
```

I want to delete all files under /archive but not its subfolders, so after deletion, the directory structure should look like:

```
/archive/
/archive/myfile/
/archive/yourfile/
```

I have tried the following two commands, but the files under the subfolders are not deleted (ie. my.txt and your.txt), anyone know why ?

```
find -L /archive ! -type d  -exec rm -rfv {} +
find -L /archive -type f  -exec rm -rfv {} +
```

Comment: You don't need an amazing solution. Why don't you erase it all, and create the directories again ? `rm` then `mkdir` ?

Comment: it's configured within a xml file which the find command will be invoked by a script.  I am testing only the find command part and a job will do this deletion periodically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use find

```
$ find . ! -type d -delete
```

make sure you're in the right path.

Comment: it should work too, did you try terminating with `\;`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  it seems that "-type f" didn't work with -delete